# eval command giving error in WSL Ubuntu

Tags: bash, colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use the solarized color scheme on wsltty using [this](https://www.steventammen.com/old-posts/basic-wsl-setup/) tutorial and everything else worked except for the part where I need to copy these commands:

```
source ~/.mintty-colors-solarized/mintty-solarized-light.sh
eval (dircolors -c ~/.dir_colors | sed 's/>&\/dev\/null$//'
```

Since I am not using `fish`, I pasted the commands in the `.bashrc` file, but it's giving me this error:

```
-bash: .bashrc: line 119: syntax error near unexpected token 'dircolors'
-bash: .bashrc: line 119: 'eval (dircolors -c ~/.dir_colors | sed 's/>&\/dev\/null$//')'
```

I don't understand what to do. The solarized color scheme is coming but the text content like `ls` output are not coming  for solarized scheme so I am sure this command has something to do with it. Can anybody help me? I don't have much experience with bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `fish` syntax in `bash`. These are two different shells and each has its own syntax, you can't just blindly copy commands from one shell to another and hope they will work.

The `eval` builtin in `fish` can apparently understand the parenthesized subshell you gave it, but that won't work in `bash`. Instead, use quotes:

```
eval "dircolors -c ~/.dir_colors | sed 's/>&\/dev\/null$//'"
```

Now I have no idea if this will work for bash, there may be other fish-specific rules in the tutorial. But this will at least run the command you are trying to run.

Comment: Sorry , you are right!! The command doesn't give an error now but it outputs lots of text and the colorscheme is still the same :( Thanks though

Comment: It's likely that they need a command substitution to `eval` the output from `sed`. The `eval` is otherwise not needed at all.

Comment: @they maybe. Although the `dircolors` ends with `export LS_COLORS` so that could work, right?

Comment: What's happening is that the background changes to solarized scheme but idk why the text color and other stuff didn't change like the output of `ls` command is still unreadable for directories and is not the solarized color scheme or maybe it is the true color scheme lol and I am thinking otherwise